# How can I check if a post with a particular slug or title exists?

Tags: php, posts, pages

I want to know if a particular page exists.
I'd like to check against either it's slug or it's title.

There is a function called 'post_exists'.
But this function seems to only work if it's invoked in hooks applicable to admin screens.

Is there a similar function that can be used in other contexts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_page_by_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) or [`get_page_by_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/).

By default, both return a page's `WP_Post` object, from which you can extract data. If the page *doesn't* exist, they'll return `null`.

You can also use them on post types other than the built-in `page`.

```
// By slug.
$slug = 'sample-page';
$page_by_slug = get_page_by_path( $slug );

// By title.
$title = 'Sample Page';
$page_by_title = get_page_by_title( $title );
```